# Github Self-hosted Action Runner not picking up jobs

Tags: linux, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

Below are the logs from svc.sh. Please help fix this issue. Whenever I want to push my project, I have to execute run.sh manual and this is real annoying me.

```
Unhandled exception. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/opt/actions-runner/_diag/Runner_20220130-012405-utc.log' is denied.
Jan 30 01:24:05 chatsfly runsvc.sh[962]: ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied
Jan 30 01:24:05 chatsfly runsvc.sh[962]: --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Jan 30 01:24:05 chatsfly runsvc.sh[962]: at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
Jan 30 01:24:05 chatsfly runsvc.sh[962]: at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)
Jan 30 01:24:05 chatsfly runsvc.sh[962]: at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preal
Jan 30 01:24:05 chatsfly runsvc.sh[962]: at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 prealloca
Jan 30 01:24:05 chatsfly runsvc.sh[962]: at GitHub.Runner.Common.HostTraceListener.CreatePageLogWriter()
Jan 30 01:24:05 chatsfly runsvc.sh[962]: at GitHub.Runner.Common.HostTraceListener..ctor(String logFileDirectory, String logFilePrefix, Int32 pageSizeLimit, Int32 retentionDays)
Jan 30 01:24:05 chatsfly runsvc.sh[962]: at GitHub.Runner.Common.HostContext..ctor(String hostType, String logFile)
Jan 30 01:24:05 chatsfly runsvc.sh[962]: at GitHub.Runner.Listener.Program.Main(String[] args)
Jan 30 01:24:07 chatsfly runsvc.sh[962]: Runner listener exited with error code null
Jan 30 01:24:07 chatsfly runsvc.sh[962]: Runner listener exit with undefined return code, re-launch runner in 5 seconds.
Jan 30 01:24:12 chatsfly runsvc.sh[962]: Starting Runner listener with startup type: service
Jan 30 01:24:12 chatsfly runsvc.sh[962]: Started listener process, pid: 10727
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Just to point it out: You are not even asking a question!

Comment: Have you checked ownership/permissions of dirs which are used by action runner?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.